# Speeding up Fourier transform and eigenvector calculation

Tags: performance-tuning, parallelization, code-review

I have a matrix $M$ in Bloch basis (momentum space). Then I have to take Fourier transform of $M$ to go to real space. The size of this lattice in real space can be fixed to some value $N_{unit}$.
Furthermore, I have to determine the eigenvectors of this real space matrix and study dynamics so it is very slow for bigger matrix sizes.

1. Let us say $M$ is a square lattice with periodic boundaries can be reduced to a matrix `hsquare (kx, ky)` by taking Fourier transform, where $k_x$ and $k_y$ are the conjugate variables to $x$ and $y$.

2. Then we take the inverse Fourier transform of `hsquare (kx, ky)` to go back to real space, i.e. matrix `hsquareFin(x,y)`.
3. Furthermore, I have to find the eigenvectors of `hsquareFin(x,y)`. That I plot on top of underlying lattice which is square lattice here.
4. Lastly, I am interested in the dynamics of how a pulse excited at a point in the real space will propagate according to the Schrödinger equation.

My MWE:

```
Nunit = 400; (* Number of unitcells *)

cond = {J1x -> 1/1, J2x -> 1, J1y -> 1/1};

hsquare[kx_, ky_] = (2 J1x Cos[kx] + 2 J1y Cos[ky] + x1) /. cond
     

square[kx_, ky_] = 2 Cos[kx] + 2 Cos[ky];


(*The Hamiltonian matrix for the Finite Case*)

DistributeDefinitions[Nunit, hsquare];
hsquareFinx[ky_] = 
  ParallelTable[#, {i, Nunit}, {j, Nunit}] &@(InverseFourierTransform[
       hsquare[kx, ky]/Sqrt[2 \[Pi]], kx, 
       x] /. {DiracDelta -> KroneckerDelta, x -> j - i, x1 -> i}) // 
   ArrayFlatten; 

DistributeDefinitions[hsquareFinx];
hsquareFin = 
  ParallelTable[#, {i, Nunit}, {j, Nunit}] &@(InverseFourierTransform[
       hsquareFinx[ky]/Sqrt[2 \[Pi]], ky, 
       y] /. {DiracDelta -> KroneckerDelta, y -> j - i}) // 
   ArrayFlatten; 


graphsq[ky_] = 
  Table[#, {i, Nunit}, {j, Nunit}] &@(InverseFourierTransform[
       square[kx, ky]/Sqrt[2 \[Pi]], kx, 
       x] /. {DiracDelta -> KroneckerDelta, x -> j - i}) // 
   ArrayFlatten;

sqg = AdjacencyGraph[
   Table[#, {i, Nunit}, {j, Nunit}] &@(InverseFourierTransform[
        graphsq[ky]/Sqrt[2 \[Pi]], ky, 
        y] /. {DiracDelta -> KroneckerDelta, y -> j - i}) // 
    ArrayFlatten, VertexLabels -> Automatic];
```

The eigenvectors are calculated

```
graphcoordsq = GraphEmbedding[sqg]; (*Generating underlying lattice*)

egvecsq = Eigenvectors[hsquareFin // N];

Manipulate[
 Show[ListDensityPlot[
   Table[
    Append[Chop@graphcoordsq[[i]], Chop@(Abs[egvecsq[[n, i]]]^2)] // 
     N, {i, Length[egvecsq[[n]]]}], PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
   PlotLabel -> "Probability density"], sqg], {n, 1, Length[egvecsq], 
  1}]
```

Is there a way to speed up the process? Because I also have to study the time dynamics of the eigenstates later.

Comment: It seems as if your matrixes have many `0` entries. I have not waited for the computations to finish. But I think the resulting matrices will be banded with a very simple structure. You should seek to exploit that, e.g. by using `SparseArray`.

Comment: @Shamina It could be better to explain you problem as mathematical problem as well.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I have rewritten my question please have a look. Feel free to let me know if I need to add something more.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I think `SparseArray` won't work here. Because I also need to generate the `AdjacencyGraph`, that will prohibit it. I can not even plot the eigenvectors later, unfortunately.

Comment: I don't understand this. For one, you have to build the `AdjacencyGraph` only after all Fourier transforms have been computed. The cost you save there with `SparseArray` should more than compensate for any conversion that you have to do afterwards. After all, you are going to reduce your computational complexity from  $O(N^2)$ (or even $O(N^4)$!?) to $O(N)$.

Comment: And what I also don't understand: `AdjacencyGraph` works perfectly also with `SparseArray`. In fact, the `Graph` data structure internally works with `SparseArray`. So what is the problem?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I don't doubt the reduction of computational time. But see this [code](https://imgur.com/6PeCoNr). Probably, I am making some mistakes

Comment: Yes, the problem is that the `Table`s still run over the full range of `1` to `Nuint`. While it is clear from the output of `FourierTransform` that most entries of the resulting matrix will be `0`. Apply `SparseArray` after the `Table` has finished does not save you the tremendous costs of the `Table`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher You mean I apply `SparseArray` to `hsquareFin`?

Comment: Yes. The `Table` in the function `hsquareFin` should not loop over all `{i,j}` pairs. Try to loop over those pairs that lead to a nonzero entry. Afterwards, you can use the `SparseArray` constructor to construct the sparse matrix from the nonzero positions and the nonzero values.

Comment: @AlexTrounev, Any insights from you would be very helpful to me!

Comment: Shamina, have you tried to determine the general rule for what entries are necessary to compute with respect to your functions that are using `InverseFourierTransform`? This way, you could avoid use of Table ahead of time and merely just assemble a `SparseArray` as others have suggested.

Comment: @CATrevillian Thanks a lot! Let me have a look into that. I don’t think I’ve fully got it but I am going to give it a try.

Comment: @Shamina Do you understand that we have to compute matrix $Nunit^2\times Nunit^2$, therefore for  `Nunit=400` it gonna be $160000\times 160000$. What is the reason to compute so big matrix? For `Nunit<=100` there is algorithm faster then your code.

Comment: @AlexTrounev I don't think I need such a big computation anymore. However, `5000X5000` is fine. Can you help me how you made it faster? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This code shows how fast `SparseArray` compare to `ParallelTable` for moderate $N_{unit}\le 10^2$. Note, that during computation code generates $N_{unit}^2\times N_{unit}^2$ matrixes `hsquareFin1=hsquareFin` and solutions `egvecsq1=egvecsq`. For $N_{unit}>100$ the computation time is limited by time of `Eigenvectors` evaluation, and therefore we can't decrease computation time for `Nunit=400` as it required. To compare computation time we can organize `Module` as follows

```
Clear["Global`*"]

cond = {J1x -> 1, J2x -> 1, J1y -> 1};

hsquare[kx_, ky_] = (2 J1x Cos[kx] + 2 J1y Cos[ky] + x1) /. cond;


square[kx_, ky_] = 2 Cos[kx] + 2 Cos[ky];


fcomp[nn_] := 
 Module[{Nunit = nn}, 
  t1 = AbsoluteTiming[DistributeDefinitions[Nunit, hsquare];
     hsquareFinx[ky_] = 
      ParallelTable[#, {i, Nunit}, {j, 
           Nunit}] &@(InverseFourierTransform[
           hsquare[kx, ky]/Sqrt[2 \[Pi]], kx, 
           x] /. {DiracDelta -> KroneckerDelta, x -> j - i, 
           x1 -> i}) // ArrayFlatten;
     
     DistributeDefinitions[hsquareFinx];
     hsquareFin = 
      ParallelTable[#, {i, Nunit}, {j, 
           Nunit}] &@(InverseFourierTransform[
           hsquareFinx[ky]/Sqrt[2 \[Pi]], ky, 
           y] /. {DiracDelta -> KroneckerDelta, y -> j - i}) // 
       ArrayFlatten;
     graphsq[ky_] = 
      Table[#, {i, Nunit}, {j, Nunit}] &@(InverseFourierTransform[
           square[kx, ky]/Sqrt[2 \[Pi]], kx, 
           x] /. {DiracDelta -> KroneckerDelta, x -> j - i}) // 
       ArrayFlatten;
     
     sqg = 
      AdjacencyGraph[
       Table[#, {i, Nunit}, {j, Nunit}] &@(InverseFourierTransform[
            graphsq[ky]/Sqrt[2 \[Pi]], ky, 
            y] /. {DiracDelta -> KroneckerDelta, y -> j - i}) // 
        ArrayFlatten, VertexLabels -> Automatic];
     (*The eigenvectors are calculated*)
     
     graphcoordsq = 
      GraphEmbedding[sqg];(*Generating underlying lattice*)
     egvecsq = Eigenvectors[hsquareFin // N // Normal];][[1]];
  
  t2 = AbsoluteTiming[
     s1 = 
      With[{n = Nunit}, 
       SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> 
          Flatten[Table[Table[i, {i, n}], {n}]], 
         Band[{1, n + 1}] -> 1, Band[{n + 1, 1}] -> 1, 
         Band[{1, 2}, {n^2, n^2}] -> Table[If[i == n, 0, 1], {i, n}], 
         Band[{2, 1}, {n^2, n^2}] -> 
          Table[If[i == n, 0, 1], {i, n}]}, {n^2, n^2}]];
     s2 = 
      With[{n = Nunit}, 
       SparseArray[{Band[{1, n + 1}] -> 1, Band[{n + 1, 1}] -> 1, 
         Band[{1, 2}, {n^2, n^2}] -> Table[If[i == n, 0, 1], {i, n}], 
         Band[{2, 1}, {n^2, n^2}] -> 
          Table[If[i == n, 0, 1], {i, n}]}, {n^2, n^2}]]; 
     sqg1 = 
      AdjacencyGraph[s2 // ArrayFlatten, VertexLabels -> Automatic]; 
     graphcoordsq1 = 
      GraphEmbedding[sqg1];(*Generating underlying lattice*)
     hsquareFin1 = (s1 // ArrayFlatten); 
     egvecsq1 = Eigenvectors[hsquareFin1 // N // Normal];][[1]]; {nn, 
   t1, t2}]
```

Here `t1` is code proposed by Shamina, and `t2` is my code with hand made array. First we call

```
fcomp[100]

Out[]= {100, 115.673, 82.1941}
```

We see that computation times `t1, t2` not so differ due to large `Eigenvectors` evaluation time. We also can compare matrixes

```
{hsquareFin1 == hsquareFin, sqg1 == sqg, egvecsq1 == egvecsq}

Out[]= {True, True, True}
```

Now we can prepare list for range `5<=Nunit<=40` and plot it separately and together with point `Nunit=100`

```
lst = Table[fcomp[i], {i, 5, 40}]

Out[]= {{5, 0.164432, 0.0043509}, {6, 0.205826, 0.0050914}, {7, 
  0.220041, 0.0064627}, {8, 0.253057, 0.0075893}, {9, 0.295401, 
  0.0123119}, {10, 0.319457, 0.0125374}, {11, 0.364707, 
  0.0142791}, {12, 0.384723, 0.016998}, {13, 0.429124, 
  0.0211146}, {14, 0.493359, 0.0247619}, {15, 0.513203, 
  0.0269879}, {16, 0.593006, 0.0354736}, {17, 0.648195, 
  0.0353599}, {18, 0.685608, 0.0465485}, {19, 0.743417, 
  0.0658679}, {20, 0.844621, 0.0619918}, {21, 0.890146, 
  0.0794076}, {22, 0.962821, 0.0800831}, {23, 1.04226, 0.108473}, {24,
   1.15235, 0.111343}, {25, 1.2167, 0.129602}, {26, 1.32637, 
  0.158706}, {27, 1.41704, 0.162905}, {28, 1.50065, 0.182941}, {29, 
  1.67359, 0.218453}, {30, 1.73249, 0.219222}, {31, 1.92085, 
  0.252828}, {32, 2.05668, 0.287723}, {33, 2.26161, 0.313731}, {34, 
  2.35782, 0.356584}, {35, 2.57131, 0.425878}, {36, 2.74442, 
  0.454498}, {37, 2.99826, 0.524451}, {38, 3.26045, 0.578484}, {39, 
  3.5149, 0.66792}, {40, 3.75821, 0.66004}}
```

[image: Figure 1]

To visualize result we can use this code

```
fm[nn_] := 
 Module[{Nunit = nn}, 
  s1 = With[{n = Nunit}, 
    SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> 
       Flatten[Table[Table[i, {i, n}], {n}]], Band[{1, n + 1}] -> 1, 
      Band[{n + 1, 1}] -> 1, 
      Band[{1, 2}, {n^2, n^2}] -> Table[If[i == n, 0, 1], {i, n}], 
      Band[{2, 1}, {n^2, n^2}] -> 
       Table[If[i == n, 0, 1], {i, n}]}, {n^2, n^2}]];
  s2 = With[{n = Nunit}, 
    SparseArray[{Band[{1, n + 1}] -> 1, Band[{n + 1, 1}] -> 1, 
      Band[{1, 2}, {n^2, n^2}] -> Table[If[i == n, 0, 1], {i, n}], 
      Band[{2, 1}, {n^2, n^2}] -> 
       Table[If[i == n, 0, 1], {i, n}]}, {n^2, n^2}]]; 
  sqg1 = AdjacencyGraph[s2 // ArrayFlatten, 
    VertexLabels -> Automatic]; graphcoordsq1 = GraphEmbedding[sqg1]; 
  hsquareFin1 = (s1 // ArrayFlatten); 
  egvecsq1 = Eigenvectors[hsquareFin1 // N // Normal]; {egvecsq1, 
   graphcoordsq1}]

With[{nn = 12}, fm[nn]; 
 Manipulate[
  Show[ListDensityPlot[
    Table[Append[Chop@graphcoordsq1[[i]], 
       Chop@(Abs[egvecsq1[[j, i]]]^2)] // N, {i, 
      Length[egvecsq1[[j]]]}], PlotLegends -> Automatic, 
    Frame -> False, PlotRange -> {{0, nn - 1/2}, {0, nn - .5}, All}, 
    ColorFunction -> Hue], sqg1], {j, 1, Length[egvecsq1], 1}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"", "", "Probability density"}, ImageMargins -> 0, 
  FrameMargins -> Small, Frame -> False]]
```

[image: Figure 2]